# Search in nested json (Azure Search)

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have CosmosDB (documentDB) with JSON, that is looking like this:

```
{
   "id": "59082f71-def1-47cc-j6w2-3fd8c0831e9c",  
   "name": "Bilbo",
   "address": 
   {  
    "street": "bla-bla-bla",        
    "city": "London",   
    "country": "Great Britain"
   }
}
```

But when I am trying to use Azure search seems that I can't use Edm.ComplexType as [it is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types)
and also I can't use Collection(Edm.String) as I have multiple fields.

Here is how I am trying to get fields:

```
SELECT c._rid, c.id, c.name, c.address.street as street, c.address.city as city, c.address.country as country FROM c WHERE c._ts >= @HighWaterMark ORDER BY c._ts
```

Comment: Are you looking to index only a specific parameter with your JSON? if not, why not index the entire document as Edm.String?

Comment: @Omri374, I can not access nested strings. I have tried to use `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts >= @HighWaterMark ORDER BY c._ts`, but without luck.

Comment: Are you querying Azure Search or CosmosDB? how is your index defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SELECT query you use looks fine. If you defined your Azure Search's data-source\indexer via Azure portal (as opposed to via REST API), you might have hit a known issue where the data source query is being ignored – we are currently working to fix that.

Meanwhile, here’s a workaround:

1. **Make sure your data source query was indeed ignored:** In Azure portal, go to the ‘Overview’ page of your search service, click on the “Data Sources” tab and select your data source.
   In the data source page, select “Edit”  - do you see the correct SELECT query in the “Query” text-box? If not correct it with your query and click “OK”
2. **Make sure your index contains the additional fields that you wanted\selected (street, city & country):** Go to the “Overview” page again, select your index from the “Indexes” tab and then select the “Fields” tab in the index page – if some fields are missing, you can add them and click “Save”
3. **Rerun or recreate your indexer:** You can either re-run your existing indexer by navigating back to the “Overview” page, selecting your indexer from the “Indexers” tab, click “Reset” and then “Run” 
   Alternatively you may delete the existing indexer (and index, if you don’t have any data you need there), and create a fresh one by clicking the “Import Data” from the “Overview” page – this time selecting an “Existing data source” in the first step.

I hope this helps.

Comment: c._ts was missing in query. When I have checked datasource as you have recommended, I have seeing that indeed select query was missing. So, I have added it back and after saving have received message that _ts is missing in query